# ¿Porque los eventos de google calendar que estoy insertando no aparecen por ningún lado?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-calendar

estoy creando un apartado de calendario en mi aplicación, para esto uso la Api para C# de google calendar, hasta ahora llamo a una clase que es la que contiene la api y esta me devuelve la lista de eventos con el id "primary" hasta aquí todo bien, el problema esta que cuando trato de insertar un evento nuevo rellenando unos campos de un formulario, este manda a la clase GoogleCalendar la solicitud con el evento, y se ejecuta dicha solicitud, todo parece correcto.

**Editado:** Sin embargo si que se muestra una excepción al tratar de crear el evento
[image: Excepcion cuando se ejecuta execute en la clase googlecalendar]

Muestro ahora la clase de google calendar.

```
class GoogleCalendar
    {
        string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        string ApplicationName = "ElEscribaDelDJ";
        private CalendarService service;

        public CalendarService Service
        {
            get { return service; }
            set { service = value; }
        }


        public GoogleCalendar()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(RecursosAplicacion.Directorios["credenciales"] + "googlecalendarcredentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            this.service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });      
        }

        public Events GetEvents()
        {
            // Define parameters of request.
            var calendarList = service.CalendarList.List().Execute();
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            //request.TimeMin = fecha;
            //request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            //request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            return events;
        }

        public Boolean CreateEvent(Event evento)
        {
            try
            {
                EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(evento, "primary");
                request.Execute();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ahora la clase que llama a esta, es a través de este metodo

```
private void BotonAgregarEvento_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Event evento = new Event();
            evento.Organizer = new Event.OrganizerData();
            evento.Organizer.DisplayName = TextoOrganizador.Text;
            evento.Organizer.Email = TextoEmail.Text;
            evento.Description = TextoAsunto.Text;
            evento.Status = ComboBoxEstado.SelectedItem.ToString();

            //Para guardar la fecha de inicio tenemos que tomar la fecha y luego la hora y minutos, los segundos son puestos 00, pues no son importantes
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
            start.DateTime = FechaInicioDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
            TimeSpan hora = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(ComboBoxHoras.SelectedItem.ToString()), int.Parse(ComboBoxMinutos.SelectedIndex.ToString()), 00);
            start.DateTime = start.DateTime + hora;

            evento.Start = start;

            //Para guardar la fecha de fin tenemos que tomar la fecha y luego la hora y minutos, los segundos son puestos 00, pues no son importantes
            EventDateTime ends = new EventDateTime();
            ends.DateTime = FechaFinDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date;

            evento.End = ends;

            _calendariogoogle.CreateEvent(evento);
        }
```

El objeto organizador lo tuve que crear porque si trataba de asignar directamente valores me decia que estaba asignando valores a un objeto nulo, todo lo que he hecho aquí ha sido basandome en este post de un usuario con la misma duda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103032/how-to-create-an-event-in-google-calendar-using-c-sharp-and-google-api

**Editado:** Estoy ahora revisando la excepcion aunque sin mucha suerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo el problema estaba en como se insertaban los estados y la fecha, que incluso siguiendo los ejemplos de otras preguntas de stackoverflow no funcionaba correctamente, he usado esto de ejemplo y funciona el problema es que luego al recuperar el evento los datos no coinciden

```
private void BotonAgregarEvento_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Event evento = new Event();           
            evento.Location = "mi casa";
            evento.Summary = "evento";
            evento.Organizer = new Event.OrganizerData();
            evento.Organizer.DisplayName = TextoOrganizador.Text;
            evento.Organizer.Email = TextoEmail.Text;
            evento.Description = TextoAsunto.Text;
            evento.Status = "confirmed";

            evento.Start = new EventDateTime();
            evento.Start.DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 3, 11, 10, 0, 0);

            evento.End = new EventDateTime();
            evento.End.DateTime = new DateTime(2019, 3, 11, 10, 30, 0);

            _calendariogoogle.CreateEvent(evento);
        }
```